# Should the business layer return persistent objects to the UI layer?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm, separation-of-concerns

Let's say I have a POJO class `Meal`. This class is mapped with an ORM (e.g. JPA + Hibernate), so I can persist it in a DB. Among other things, this class contains a `List<Dish> dishes` (Dish being another mapped POJO) that is lazily loaded by the ORM.

Now I have a business layer method `Meal getNextDueMeal()`. This is invoked by the UI layer to then display the meal to the user. Of course, the dishes that make up the meal should also be displayed.

But how should I deal with this? If I try to iterate over the list returned by `getMeals()` naively, I would get a `LazyInitializationException`. I could maintain an `EntityManger` in the UI layer e.g. by using Spring's `@Transactional` annotation. But then the object returned from the business logic would stay persistent, i.e. if I somehow modify the `Meal`-"POJO" in the UI, it will automatically get saved once I return from the `@Transactional`-method, which may not be what I want.

**tl;dr:** Should the business layer return persistent objects to the UI-Layer? And if not, how do I deal with lazy loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're working with a remote interface, it's not a good idea to return your entities as your *Business Layer* return values. You can define some *DTO* or *Data Transfer Objects* and populate them from fetched entities and return those DTOs as the return value.

> Should the business layer return persistent objects to the UI-Layer?
>   And if not, how do I deal with lazy loading?

About *Lazy Loading*, you can populate all the required values in the business layer into the DTO object, hence, in your UI layer all the required attributes are loaded and you won't encounter those `LazyInitializationException` exceptions.

#### How it Works?

---

Quoting from [PoEAA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420):

> The fields in a Data Transfer Object are fairly simple, being
>   primitives, simple classes like `String`s and `Date`s, or other Data
>   Transfer Objects. Any structure between data transfer objects should
>   be a simple graph structure—normally a hierarchy—as opposed to the
>   more complicated graph structures that you see in a Entity.

In your case, you probably would have a `MealDto` and a `DishDto`, something like this:

```
public class MealDto {
    private String name;
    private List<DishDto> dishes;

    // getters and setters
}
```

You can use another abstractions responsible for assembling the DTO from the corresponding Entity. For example, you can use a `MealAssembler`:

```
public class MealAssembler {
    public MealDto toDto(Meal meal) {
        MealDto dto = new MealDto();
        dto.setName(meal.getName);
        // populate the other stuff    

        return dto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sort of depends on how you implement your view, or UI, layer.

Remember that JSP and JSF are `Server Side` views. This means they will have access to everything in the JVM at the time the view is rendered. In this case, I see no reason why the `service layer` (or business layer), cannot pass the entities retrieved from the database to the views to be rendered.

There is a lot of popularity with `Client Side` view rendering with Frameworks such as AngularJs and jQuery. This means that once an `object` is passed to the view, it no longer is part of the JVM, and so you have to build a object that will not need to make any further calls to the JVM to be rendered. In this case it is typical to marshal the object into a JSON or XML representation and sent it to the client.

In both cases, once the Entity has been handed to the controller layer, it is outside of the transaction and will no longer be able to make JPA calls or JDBC calls. This can result in `LazyInitializationExceptions` if you try to reference properties that haven't been initialized. One difference between server side and client side views is that in the `server side` technologies no `Lazy` problem arises when uninitialized properties aren't referenced. When an object is mashalled for `client side` technologies however, the marshaller will try to marshall all the fields, which can result in a `lazy` exception even though ultimately the view isn't using those fields. In this case, you want to create a `DTO` or Data Transfer Object that only has the fields needed, which the marshaller will be able to marshall without any exceptions.

The way to deal with `LazyInitializationExceptions` for fields that the view needs is to be sure they are initialized before the view attempts to access them. This generally requires several queries or a join, which is a somewhat different question.